# Angular html5 mode in Mean stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

**routes.js**

```
app.route('/*')
    .get(indexController.render);
```

**indexController.js**

```
exports.render=function(req, res){

        res.render('index');

    }
```

**config.js**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I am trying to implement html5 mode in my mean application. This did not work. Anything wrong in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.render=function(req, res){
    //Your path to the html with .html
    res.render('index.html');
}
```

Comment: i already mentioned my views location in express configuration file

Comment: `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/', module.renderIndex);

module.renderIndex = function(req,res){
        res.render('index.html')
};`

Comment: To know how to do it you can check my website source code, look at the server.js and routes/routes.js ;)

https://github.com/AugustoL/website/tree/master/website-front

Answer (score 1):

In the index page, you should put this:

```
<base href="/">
```

to help html5mode.

Comment: This answer isn't clear to me; can you expand it a bit and format it?

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that angular can handle your routes without a hash bang url (#/), you must add this code to your main `index.html`:

```
<base href="/">
```

This is to make sure that angular knows that this page is the main page and that routes should dynamically be populated in this page.